# Check if array can be sorted in ascending order in single swap

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array say `$a=array(1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3);` which can be sorted in swap in ascending order e.g. swap 6 and 3. If this is possible then my function should return true, if not then false. For example array(10, 30, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70) return true and array(80, 10, 30, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70) return false because it will take more than one swap to sort the array in ascending order so far i have done this..

```
function checksort($arr) {
    for ($i = count($arr) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        if ($arr[$i] < $arr[$i - 1]) {
            $j = $i - 1;
            while ($j > 0) {
                $j--;
                $temp = $arr[$i];
                $arr[$i] = $arr[$j + 1];
                $arr[$j + 1] = $temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $sortedarray = $arr;
    sort($arr);
    if ($sortedarray == $arr) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
$a = array(1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3);
echo checksort($a);
```

The result I am getting is false where as it should be true. I know the issue is because the array is getting rewritten at every true condition in for loop but at the same time `$i` gets -1 and it reaches to the point where it can not go further and check the entire array for the condition.

Comment: couldent you just compare the original to a stored version of the array, if more than 2 positions have changed, return false.

Comment: This is not a full sorting algorithm, it only does 1 pass.

Comment: What if the array is already sorted? Return `true` or `false`???

Comment: @tim at which point you've already sorted the array and why are we even checking? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function will only swap items next to each other and not at the other ends of the array.

It may be simpler to just look at the differences in the original array and a sorted array using [`array_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) which means that this will give the number of items out of order.  If there are more than 2 then return false, otherwise true...

```
function checksort($arr){
    $b = $arr;
    sort($b);
    return count(array_diff_assoc($arr, $b))<=2;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `<= 2` or `< 3` though, or maybe `== 2` depending on what they want if already sorted.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I've updated it - I sometimes get confused as to what is true/false :-/